# What Does This Command Do? Should i be worried?

Tags: centos, node.js

So I was debugging my code when I see these few lines in my log:

```
GET /cgi/common.cgi 302 8.015 ms - 23
GET /stssys.htm 302 2.928 ms - 23
GET / 200 134.922 ms - 9896
POST /command.php 302 33.826 ms - 23
GET /language/Swedish${IFS}&&echo${IFS}610cker>qt&&tar${IFS}/string.js 302 1.049 ms - 23
```

Could this affect me or my system? What can I do to protect against this? I'm not using CGI or PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an attempt at command injection. `IFS` is basically a space in this situation, and `&&` executes multiple commands. So you have:

```
/language/Swedish && echo 610cker > qt && tar /string.js
```

Which tries to execute three commands:

```
/language/Swedish   <-- where the injection takes place
echo 610cker > qt   <-- write 610cker to file qt
tar /string.js      <-- compress file string.js (but the command is invalid)
```

The commands do not really make sense and are not used to exploit your system, but likely used to test if it is vulnerable.

If you google `610cker` you will find some reports about an exploit on a D-Link router (although the payload looks slightly different) and other systems (see eg [here](http://www.kerneronsec.com/2016/02/remote-code-execution-in-cctv-dvrs-of.html), using the same payload).

As with all log entries of this type, it is almost certainly a scanner. If your system is not vulnerable and there are no other signs of intrusion, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Wish I could upvote your answer more than once